# The rule of jne in code compiled by clang

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, llvm

Source code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

do {
    printf("heihei");
}while (1 < 2);

return 0;}
```

Compiled:

```
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
movb    $0, %al
callq   _printf
movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill

movb    $1, %al
testb   $1, %al
jne LBB0_1
jmp LBB0_3
LBB0_3:
```

Obviously, this do-while loop is infinite.
According to my knowledge, testb $1, %al would set ZF to 1. Since jne jumps only when ZF is 0 (jne: jump option : ~ZF), how come the flow would jump back to LBB0_1 ?

Btw, do you have any recommendation on books for learning Clang generated assembly code and all other related content? (specifically from objective-c code)

Comment: What difference does the compiler make?  Obviously different compilers (and options) will generate different code, but at the end of the day it's a question of understanding the assembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WW

The description of the `test` instruction:

> TEST -- Logical Compare
>
> Computes the bit-wise logical AND of first operand (source 1 operand)
>   and the second operand (source 2 operand) and sets the SF, ZF, and PF
>   status flags according to the result. The result is then discarded.

In this case `jne` is synonymous with `jnz`. The instruction is often used to test for a zero value so you will see things like:

```
testb   %al, %al
jz      somewhere
```

To your other question, what you are looking for is the GAS (Gnu Assembler) syntax and you can find a world of information on the internet but check out the [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax) link.